# How to display ShowCase on Alert Dialog (Android)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, alert, showcaseview

I've used the library `com.github.mreram: showcaseview: 1.1`.

When I want to show the showcase on the alert, it shows the showcase behind the alert.

**I've used almost all of the ShowCases but they all have the same problem.**

```
private GuideView ShowCaseView;
private GuideView.Builder ShowCaseBuilder;
private Alert Alert;

@oClick(R.id.bTest)
public void onClick() {
    Alert = new Alert(this);
    Alert.ShowAlert();

    ImageView imgCancel = ButterKnife.findById(Alert, R.id.imgAlertTitle);

    ShowCaseBuilder = new GuideView.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("Test")
                            .setContentText("Test")
                            .setTargetView(imgCancel)
                            .setContentTypeFace(AppController.Iran)
                            .setTitleTypeFace(AppController.IranBold)
                            .setDismissType(DismissType.anywhere)
                            .setGuideListener(new GuideListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDismiss(View view) {
                                    return;
                                }
                            });

      ShowCaseView = ShowCaseBuilder.build();
      if (!ShowCaseView.isShowing())
           ShowCaseView.show();
}
```

**The result looks like this**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mZFG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create your own custom Dialor Alert. And then include the showcase code inside it.
Example of how to make a CustomDialogAlert:

https://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-alert-dialog-example-android-studio.html

[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Or try making a class like:

```
 public class ViewDialog {

    public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialogbox_otp);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_file_path);
        text.setText(msg);

        Button dialogBtn_cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        dialogBtn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        Button dialogBtn_okay = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_okay);
        dialogBtn_okay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        ShowCaseBuilder = new GuideView.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Test")
                        .setContentText("Test")
                        .setTargetView(imgCancel)
                        .setContentTypeFace(AppController.Iran)
                        .setTitleTypeFace(AppController.IranBold)
                        .setDismissType(DismissType.anywhere)
                        .setGuideListener(new GuideListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(View view) {
                                return;
                            }
                        });

        MyShowCaseView = ShowCaseBuilder.build();
        if (!ShowCaseView.isShowing())
            ShowCaseView.show();
             dialog.show();
        }
  }
```

Also, because of the issue pointed out by @MikeM, You need to create a class, that extends GuideView and override the show so that in the show() it adds the view in the proper place

```
public void show() {
    this.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    this.setClickable(false);

    ((ViewGroup) ((Activity) getContext()).getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this);
    AlphaAnimation startAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    startAnimation.setDuration(APPEARING_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    startAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    this.startAnimation(startAnimation);
    mIsShowing = true;
}
```

My full MyGuideView I tried:

https://pastebin.com/LkES1Vih

And I do:

```
    ShowCaseView = new showCaseBuilder.build()
    ShowCaseView.setLayout(parentView)
    if (!ShowCaseView.isShowing())
        ShowCaseView.show()
```

Comment: Did you test this? Looking at the source, it seems it's set up to work in only an `Activity`, as it explicitly adds itself to an `Activity`'s `DecorView`.

Comment: I've used the Custom Alert Dialog. If you look at the code I made a type of my Alert but still, it has the same problem. @MikeM.

Comment: @Mohammad Yeah, that library, as is, will only work with an `Activity`. If you want to modify the source, you might be able to get it to work with a `Dialog`, depending on exactly what effect you're wanting. You might also be able to find another library that already works with `Dialog`s.

Comment: I've used almost all of the ShowCases but they all have the same problem.@MikeM.

Comment: @MikeM. you are right, it does appear on the Activity, cause it's linked to the decor. Sorry, with converting to kotlin and working on my own stuff, took a while to test

Comment: @Mohammad I edited my response, I am trying it now on my part, and will let you know if I manage something.

Comment: @Mohammad sorry mate, I tried, it does appear on the Dialog and not the main view, but it appears behind, not on top. Which is weird. If You want to try more, maybe you manage, I will put my code of the modified GuideView in a edit

Comment: **GuideMessageView** Class is not Exist.Does the library need it?@MikeM.

Comment: Well, I got it to work in the `Dialog`, but as soon as I did, I realized that it's probably not what @Mohammad wants, since the effect appears strictly within the `Dialog`'s bounds. I'd imagine they want a fullscreen overlay, on top of the `Dialog`. If that's the case, it'd probably be easier to create an `Activity` that mimics a `Dialog` – e.g., with the `View` centered in a transparent background – and just using the library, as is, in that `Activity`.

Comment: @MikeM. I also copied inside my project the "GuideMessageView" class to make it work. (to be visible to the MyGuideView.
And yes, I agree with you, If he wants it to appear outside the bounds of the view, I would rather use a view in the activity, that acts as a dialog, and put a shadow in it's background

Comment: The modified code at **https://pastebin.com/LkES1Vih** has a class **GuideMessageView** which doesn't exist, does it need a library?@rosualin

Comment: create a class with that name in your project, where you created the MyGuideView and add this:
https://github.com/mreram/ShowCaseView/blob/master/showcaseviewlib/src/main/java/smartdevelop/ir/eram/showcaseviewlib/GuideMessageView.java
The class from the library is private, so it cannot be accessed from a your package, adding it like this, works